# How to save urls of images from a text file?

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with many URL's and have imported them into matlab via a cell with 1400 rows of URL's.

How do I take these urls of images and save them with a pre-determined size into a sub-folder?

```
urlsToImgs = importdata('ImageURLS.txt');
for i = 1:1
    outfilename = websave(['PosImage: ', num2str(i)],['' urlsToImgs{i} '']);   
end
```

This makes an error: **The file name contains characters that are not contained in the filesystem encoding.
 Certain operations may not work as expected.**

Im guessing since I pasted it from the web it contains an invisible character, how can I delete this?

Comment: Please show the format of the desired input an output. What is the code you wrote supposed to do?

Comment: It creates a cell 1400 x 1 of URL's. E.G http::/ . . ..jpg. I want to save them in a specific size (227 x 227) into a sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

delete colon in filename. i.e.) change 'PosImage: ' to 'PosImage_'
you may not allowed to create file with special characters.